# Can I chain multiple "or" (||) operators in C#?

Tags: c#, operators

I want to add items in one string list "Slist" to a new list, IF the items in "Slist" are named Tom, Dick or Harry.
Can I use the following code?

```
var newlist = Slist.Where(x => x == "Tom" || x == "Dick" || x == "Harry" )).ToList();
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your code is a valid C# statement. I don't get what you mean if you can. I doubt that you have written this in an IDE and it does not compile. So you must trying to ask something else possibly ? Please try to describe what is the problem you face. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To actually answer your question, yes, this is a valid C# statement. The predicate that you pass to the `Where()` method will be evaluated to a boolean value, as expected.

The following code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string[] Slist = new string[] {"Tom", "Max", "Dick", "Harry"};
        string[] filtered = Slist.Where(n => n == "Tom" || n == "Dick").ToArray();

        foreach (string n in filtered) Console.WriteLine(n);
    }
}
```

will produce the following output

```
Tom
Dick
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/5KL4as

Just a friendly reminder though, try to post more precise questions on Stack Overflow. It's hard to see how this question could **really** help someone else in the future because anyone could just try it in a .NET fiddle or an IDE.